# How to create formgroup with a data that has an array of data in angular 9?

Tags: angular, formgroups

How to create formgroup with a data that has an array of data.
also how to save bind it to that data?

Data format

```
{  
     id: 0,
     tenantId: 0, 
     qty: 0,
     dateInvoiced: '',  
     status: '', 
     services: 
     { 
        service1: false,
        service2: false,
        service3: false, 
        otherServices: '',
    }
}
```

How to create formgroup with the array of services?

```
        var group: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
          id: new FormControl(''),
          tenantId: new FormControl(''),
          qty: new FormControl(''),
          dateInvoiced: new FormControl(''),
          status: new FormControl(''),
          services: new FormControl(''), //how to do services array here?
        });
        this.dynamicFormGroup = group
```

How to save the services in the data on top? Thank you

```
  <mat-slide-toggle formControlName="services.service1">Service 1</mat-slide-toggle>
  <mat-slide-toggle formControlName="services.service2">Service 2</mat-slide-toggle>
  <mat-slide-toggle formControlName="services.service3">Service 3</mat-slide-toggle>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you has not an Array, you need create a FormGroup,

```
  var group: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
      ...
      services: new FormGroup({
         service1:new FormControl(),
         service2:new FormControl(),
         service3:new FormControl(),
         otherServices:new FormControl()
      })
    });
```

And use [nested from groups](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#creating-nested-form-groups)

If you want to create a formArray use

```
      services: new FormArray([
         new FormControl(),
         new FormControl(),
         new FormControl(),
         new FormControl()
      })
```

In a nested FromGroup just use

```
<form [formGroup]="dynamicFormGroup">
  <input formControlName="id">
  ....
  <div formGroupName="services">
    <input formControlName='service1'>
      ...
  </div>
</form>
```

In a FormArray we need take account that is a FormArray of FormControls

```
<form [formGroup]="dynamicFormGroup">
  <input formControlName="id">
  ....
  <div formArrayName=="services">
   <div *ngFor="let control of dynamicFormGroup.get('services').controls;let i=index">
    <input [formControlName]="i">
   </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, how do you call the name in html in formControlName=""?

Comment: thanks for you response, how can i save the two formgroup as one? like the data format code i ask in my question. thank you!

Comment: the dynamicFormGroup.value is like your data (to check it , simply write in html `<pre>{{dynamicFormGroup?.value|json}}</pre>`

Comment: but the services is from services formgroup. how can i save both dynamicformgroup and services formgroup in one object with the format like i have in my question?